# Testing GCM in simple JUnit-Tests

Tags: java, junit, google-cloud-messaging

I searched a lot but I found no solution. I'm pretty sure that it is not possible but maybe one of you how you can do this.

I have a Server that can send Push-Notifications to my app. Therefore I use the Google Cloud Messageing Service https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Unfortunately the rules for when a notification should be sended are not that easy. So I would feel a lot better if I could write JUnit-Testcases that can subscripe to the project and receive these notifications. And it would be very helpful if I could test this against a real system.

Howoever it seems that you can only recive push-notifications in real Android and IPhone -Apps. Additionally there is a Chrome-App thatcan do it https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm

**Is there any possibility to receive a GCM Push-Notification in a Java desktop application?**

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be no Solution for this I wrote Something that suits my needs. Feel free if to do anything you want with this:

https://github.com/codemaker219/gcmproxy